# Custom metadata name in metadata.txt and plugins.xml

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

It is possible/recommended to add a new metadata name in metadata.txt and plugins.xml or is a closed format and we can have only the metadata name specified in [Plugin metadata section](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html#id5) ?

For example, I would like to add

```
<environment>SANDBOX</environment>
```

and the code will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
    <pyqgis_plugin name="Pluginname" version="plugin.4.0.400">
        <description>Plugin Description here</description>
        <homepage>http://www.plugi-home-page.uk</homepage>
        <qgis_minimum_version>2.14</qgis_minimum_version>
        <file_name>Plugin.zip</file_name>
        <author_name>Author name</author_name>
        <download_url>http://repository-url/QgisPlugins/plugin.zip</download_url>
        <environment>SANDBOX</environment>
    </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>
```

The startup.py will do an automatic upgrade of the plugin, if a new version is available or if the user changed the current repository (in current situation we are using multiple repositories, one for each environment: sanbox, prod... etc), so. a new tag to tell us for which environment is the available plugin, will be very useful.